# How can I verify free and occupied cache of a mobile?

Tags: android

I want to first verify free and occupied cache of the mobile in which my `Android` application is installed, then
1 - If the free cache is more than 200 Mega bytes, I occupy 200 Mega bytes for Picasso cache (increase the default cache size)
2 - If the free cache is less than 200 Mega bytes, I message the user for low space

How can I verify free and occupied cache of the mobile?